# Help to make the equations of state of qubits?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-state

.., and find their cofacents, after H(q1) ->CNOT(q1,q2) -> H(q2)

On the website https://algassert.com/
[image]
The preparation is like this. I understand so far

[The preparation is like this. I understand so far](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B1,%22H%22%5D%5D%7D)
[Option 1.  H(q1) -> CNOT(controlller q1, q2) -> H(q1)](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B%22H%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22H%22%5D%5D%7D) 
Q1= 0.5a +0.5b
Q2= -0.5a + 0.5b
[Option 2.  H(q1) -> CNOT(controlller q1, q2) -> H(q2)](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B%22H%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,%22H%22%5D%5D%7D) 
Q1= 0.5a -0.5b  // threre '-'
Q2= 0.5a + 0.5b
What will be the equations of state? For a qubit Q1, Q2 in 2 variants???
Can you write a complete matrix for 2 variants,
Q1----H--O--H  Q1
|
Q--------X---

```
Q1= a0|0⟩ + a1|1⟩
Q2= b0|0⟩ + b1|1⟩
.....
Q1*H= (a0+a1|1⟩ +a1-a1|>0) * 1/sqrt(2)
Q1*H*Cnot(q1,q2)
1 0 0 0   |(a0+a1)*b0|00⟩|  
0 1 0 0 * |(a0+a1)*b1|01⟩|
0 0 0 1   |(a0-a1)*b0|10⟩| *1/sqrt(2)
0 0 1 0   |(a0-a1)*b1|11⟩|
     =((a0+a1)*b0|00⟩+ (a0+a1)*b1|01⟩ +(a0-a1)*b1|10⟩ + (a0-a1)*b0|11⟩ )*1/sqrt(2)
```

Is it right?

then  Q1 * Hadamard ??????
or Q2 * Hadamard ??????
How do I multiply my equation of state by the Hadamard Gate? Will you be able to write the full formula while continuing to multiply by my equation,
I just need to understand this.
What should be multiplied by what when I apply the Hadamard Gate to Qubit 1 or Qubit? What is changing ?

[And in this scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuv6R.png), why, when changing on one scheme, the coefficients a, b change on the other, if they were not connected by 2 qubit operations?

Wow, while I was writing the question, I may have understood something, but I will ask a question.
Why are the circles not symmetrical when I apply Hadamard Gate to Qubit_1 or Qubit_2
[image: Q1*H]
[image: Q2*H]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.